# How to check which primefaces ajax event triggered into java method

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

let's say we have two types of events that will be directed to the same method as mentioned in the below example

```html
<p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{bean.eventype}"/>
<p:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.eventype}"/>
```

and here is the bean method for example

```java
public void eventype(){
  println("");
}
```

1. The question is, is it possible if I want to identify which value came from which events in eventype method?
2. Is it possible to differentiate both mentioned events in eventype method?

Edited:
I did try to add `eventype(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)` and use event.getSource() but it seems like am just getting the source details like `org.inputtext.component@something`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of event is posted in the request in order for the component being able to decode it to trigger the correct event. The parameter name is `javax.faces.behavior.event`, which you can get like:

```java
String eventType = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
        .getExternalContext()
        .getRequestParameterMap()
        .get("javax.faces.behavior.event");
```

This is implemented in PrimeFaces like:

https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/042b5a14116cd4a279a114883a8575e0788494b8/primefaces/src/main/java/org/primefaces/util/ComponentUtils.java#L197-L224

Note that you can also use the PrimeFaces constant `Constants.RequestParams.PARTIAL_BEHAVIOR_EVENT_PARAM` in your code instead of hardcoding `"javax.faces.behavior.event"`.